# Can't find the way to useSelector from redux-toolkit within event handler and pass params to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

There is an event handler for click and when it triggered i want to pull specific data from redux using selector where all logic many-to-many is implemented. I need to pass id to it in order to receive its individual data. Based on rules of the react the hooks can be called in function that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.

So what is the way to solve my problem ?

```js
const handleMediaItemClick = (media: any): void => {
    // For example i check media type and use this selector to pull redux data by id
    const data = useSelector(playlistWithMediaSelector(imedia.id));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use local state value to track that.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [imediaId, setImediaId] = useState(null);

  const data = useSelector(playlistWithMediaSelector(imediaId));

  function handleMediaClick(id) {
    setImediaId(id)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something on data
  }, [imediaId, data])

  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Does that help?

EDIT: I gather that what you want to do is to be able to call the selector where you need. Something like (considering the code above) `data(id)` in `handleMediaClick`. I'd bet you gotta return a curried function from `useSelector`, rather than value. Then you would call it. Alas, I haven't figured out how to that, if it's at all possible and whether it's an acceptable pattern or not.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, you cannot call hooks inside functions. You call a hook inside a functional component and use that value inside the function. The `useSelector` hook updates the variable each time the state changes and renders that component.

Also, when you get data with `useSelector`, you should write the reducer name you need from the redux state.

```
 const CustomComponent = () => {
      // The data will be updated on each state change and the component will be rendered
      const data = useSelector((state) => state.REDUCER_NAME);

      const handleMediaItemClick = () => {
          console.log(data);
      };
 }
```

You can check this page for more information.[https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector](http://useSelector%20Hook)

Comment: But how can i pass params to selector ? By clicking for example i get unique id each time. And how to pass that id to selector ?